# Should I synchronize on a ReferenceQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency

I was taking a look at the source code for `WeakHashMap` and stumbled across this:

```
private final ReferenceQueue<Object> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();

private void expungeStaleEntries() {
    for (Object x; (x = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
        synchronized (queue) {
           /* snip */
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this method synchronize on the `ReferenceQueue`? [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) itself does not make claims to be thread safe:

> Like most collection classes, this class is not synchronized. A
>   synchronized WeakHashMap may be constructed using the
>   Collections.synchronizedMap method.

Which led me to believe that this implementation detail is to, somehow, ensure the thread safety of the `ReferenceQueue` itself (since the GC will be modifying it from its own `Thread`). However, [the documentation for `ReferenceQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) does not mention anything about any concurrency concerns, and taking a look at the source code for `ReferenceQueue` reveals that it doesn't even synchronize on itself (it uses an internal lock).

Why is `WeakHashMap` synchronizing on its `ReferenceQueue`? Should I synchronize on a `ReferenceQueue` every time I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [`ReferenceQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) you will see that it explicitly supports threading inside the platform, because it states that the `remove()` method will block until a new entry is available.

The `synchronized` you see in `WeakHashMap` is about ensuring that multiple threads accessing a `ReferenceQueue` are properly synchronized.

You might find this [related bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6425537) interesting.

To answer your question, I think external synchronization of the `ReferenceQueue` is not required if you ensure it is only accessed by a single thread.  I would not use (and can't think of a good reason) to use a single `ReferenceQueue` as a consumer from multiple threads.

Comment: +1 Nice find - Interesting how a read method may modify the map.

Comment: @andersoj Ahh, that bug report makes it  clear. Since calling `size` on a `WeakHashMap` might modify the underlying map, a user who concurrently calls `size` on one might inadvertently corrupt it. This behavior is contrary to most (all?) other JDK `Map` implementations which would allow multiple threads to read their contents with no problems, so they decided to make the class a little bit thread-safe in order to maintain consistency with the `Map` specification.

Comment: @John Vint for example LinkedHashMap get modifies the map because it stores acess ordering